# How to add RDS Proxy to AWS Lambda using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I have few lambdas that are connecting to RDS via RDS Proxy. As part of the deployment I need to add a step to attach RDS Proxy to the lambda. But I am unable to find right CLI command to do that. I did not see any methods in Lambda side or RDS side to do this.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think as off now there is no CLI command for this! But using RDS proxy can be achieved just by using the proxy URL for connections instead of original DB instance

Comment: true, but adding proxy to lambda configures required IAM role or something like that. May be I will check what is happening there.